Is there an error in this restatement of Euler's proof of his Rotation Theorem?
This is a discussion of Euler's Rotation Theorem.  From my understanding of the terminology of image and preimage, I conclude there is an error in the explanation of Figure 2.  Is there, in fact such an error in the discussion on the webpage?   I am curious to know what is in Euler's original proof.
https://handwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem

When a sphere is moved around its centre it is always possible to find a diameter whose direction in the displaced position is the same as in the initial position.


Proof


Euler's original proof was made using spherical geometry and therefore whenever he speaks about triangles they must be understood as spherical triangles.


To arrive at a proof, Euler analyses what the situation would look like if the theorem were true. To that end, suppose the yellow line in Figure 1 goes through the center of the sphere and is the axis of rotation we are looking for, and point $O$ is one of the two intersection points of that axis with the sphere. Then he considers an arbitrary great circle that does not contain $O$ (the blue circle), and its image after rotation (the red circle), which is another great circle not containing $O$. He labels a point on their intersection as point $A.$ (If the circles coincide, then $A$ can be taken as any point on either; otherwise $A$ is one of the two points of intersection.)


Now $A$ is on the initial circle (the blue circle), so its image will be on the transported circle (red). He labels that image as point $a.$ Since $A$ is also on the transported circle (red), it is the image of another point that was on the initial circle (blue) and he labels that preimage as $α$ (see Figure 2). Then he considers the two arcs joining $α$ and $a$ to $A.$ These arcs have the same length because arc $αA$ is mapped onto arc $Aa.$ Also, since $O$ is a fixed point, triangle $αOA$ is mapped onto triangle $AOa,$ so these triangles are isosceles, and arc $AO$ bisects angle $∠αAa.$


etc.


From the illustrations below, it is evident that the point $a$ is the image of the point $\alpha,$ and not the image of the point $A$ in Figure 2.
In my illustrations, the point of initial consideration is $\mathfrak{A}_o.$  This point is moved to $\mathfrak{A}_\bullet.$  So my $\mathfrak{A}_o$ and $\mathfrak{A}_\bullet$ are $\alpha$ and $a$ of Figure 2 respectively.  What I call $\mathfrak{B}_\bullet$ is $A$ of Figure 2, and my $\mathfrak{B}_o$ is the preimage of $A$ which is not shown in Figure 2.
Setup prior to motion:

System in motion:
The labels do not following the moving (green) points.

Final state of the system:


I have to wonder why Euler would even present such an elaborate "proof", considering the much simpler proof by observing that the axis of rotation is the line through the center normal to the plane determined by the original diameter of the point and that of the image point  after motion.

Euler's theorem holds for all rigid motions of the sphere that keep its center fixed.

And?  Exclude the case in which the original and transformed diameters coincide.  The diameter through the original point "cross" the diameter through the transformed point determines a plane.  There is exactly one diameter through the center normal to that plane.  No other diameter shares this normality property with both point diameters.  The details of the "motion" are irrelevant.  That seems pretty proven to me.

What makes you think that the north and south poles you thus obtained were held fixed in the rigid motion I performed? Big gap in your reasoning imo.

There is no mention of intermediate position in the theorem.  "When a sphere is moved around its centre it is always possible to find a diameter whose direction in the displaced position is the same as in the initial position."

In your proof (two comments earlier) that I am criticising you take an arbitrary original point and its image under the rigid motion and claim that the motion was a rotation fixing the plane that contains the original, its image and the center of the sphere. What you don't prove is that you get the same rotation when you do this with any other point. Way too simplistic. Huge gap in that reasoning. Be humble when you challenge Euler.

The intersection of the geodesics normal through the midpoints of the geodesic displacements of two mutually perpendicular diameters will be on the axis of rotation since it contains the centers of curvature of circular arcs connecting the displaced points.  This determines the position of every other point of the solid sphere. If only one of the diameters is displaced, the other is the axis of rotation.

After reading what Euler wrote (PDF), and following his diagram, I am able to reproduce the illustration on the webpage.  The proof there doesn't strictly follow Euler, which I am still reading.
Update:
I believe the available English translation of Euler's original Latin document is less than perfect.  Some of it simply doesn't make sense (to me). For example "... then the point $O$ searched for must be situated somewhere on this arc $AB$."  I can't force my mind to invent an interpretation of that statement which makes sense.
Since I am by no means fluent in Latin, the best I can do is interpolate.
I believe the (ex post facto?) hash-mark near $b$ should lie on the other circle in Euler's original drawing:

The gist of Euler's argument is that, for the axis of rotation through $O$ to exist, the structure determined by $\left\{O,A,B,C\right\}$ is congruent with that determined by $\left\{O,a,b,c\right\}.$  He then shows how to determine such point $O.$
My interpretation of Euler's illustration is:
Initial Setup
The blue post (not show by Euler) is the axis of symmetry of the blue geodesic. At this instant, the red (not depicted) and blue geodesics are coincident. The green post is the coveted axis of rotation through the point $O$. The yellow geodesic is neither depicted nor mentioned by Euler. It is correctly depicted in the illustration on the website.

System in Transition
The blue axis and geodesic as well as the green axis remain fixed in space, while the sphere with the red geodesic and corresponding axis move rigidly together.

Final State of the System
This is the state depicted by Euler.  His argument is that, if the coveted $O$ exists then the congurences
$$\begin{aligned}
 \left(OA\right) &\cong \left(Oa\right)\\
 \angle{OAB} &\cong \angle{Oab}\\
 \triangle{OA\alpha} &\cong \triangle{OAa}
\end{aligned}$$
hold.  He then uses the bisected isosceles triangle (magenta) to locate $O$ so that it satisfies these conditions.


Using my illustrations, I add a point $\mathfrak{B}_*$ (Bee-splat,) which is the image of $\mathfrak{B}_\bullet$ (Bee-spot) under the transformation bringing $\mathfrak{A}_o$ (Eh?-naught) into $\mathfrak{A}_\bullet.$  I also impose the requirement that the geodesic $\overline{\mathfrak{A}_o\mathfrak{C}}$ meet the blue reference geodesic perpendicularly.
We have yet to show that the transformed image $\overline{\mathfrak{A}_\bullet\mathfrak{C}^\prime}$ (label $\mathfrak{C}^\prime$ is not depicted) of $\overline{\mathfrak{A}_o\mathfrak{C}}$ intersects $\overline{\mathfrak{A}_o\mathfrak{C}}$ at $\mathfrak{C},$ i.e., $\mathfrak{C}\equiv\mathfrak{C}^\prime .$
Since the yellow geodesic intersecting $\mathfrak{B}_\bullet$ is defined to be a bisector of $\angle{\mathfrak{A}_o\mathfrak{B}_\bullet\mathfrak{A}_\bullet},$ we have $\angle{\mathfrak{A}_o\mathfrak{B}_\bullet\mathfrak{C}}\cong\angle{\mathfrak{A}_\bullet\mathfrak{B}_\bullet\mathfrak{C}^\prime}.$  The roles of $\mathfrak{B}_o$ and $\mathfrak{B}_*$ are reversed in the inverse of the transformation $\left\{\mathfrak{B}_o,\mathfrak{A}_o,\mathfrak{B}_\bullet\right\}\mapsto\left\{\mathfrak{B}_\bullet,\mathfrak{A}_\bullet,\mathfrak{B}_*\right\},$ that is $\left\{\mathfrak{B}_\bullet,\mathfrak{A}_\bullet,\mathfrak{B}_*\right\}\mapsto\left\{\mathfrak{B}_o,\mathfrak{A}_o,\mathfrak{B}_\bullet\right\}.$  Thus symmetric reflection reveals that the segments $\mathfrak{A}_o\mathfrak{B}_\bullet$ and $\mathfrak{A}_\bullet\mathfrak{B}_\bullet$ are congruent.  Thus we invoke that angle-side-angle theorem to conclude $\mathfrak{C}\equiv\mathfrak{C}^\prime.$

